# LaTeX Referenz in English

Tags: documentation

Not too long ago, I think it was at the beginning of November, the [LaTeX Referenz](http://www.lehmanns.de/page/latexreferenz) by Herbert Voß was released for free, but its in German (am not saying its a bad thing). Are there any plans on translating this into English or can anyone do it? It is a very good quick reference and would love to see an English translation. If any one knows where I can get one I would appreciate it. May be Herbert Voß could answer this :-).

Comment: @egreg and the rest of TeX.SX, I have proposed to move my question to meta because it may lead to one end answer with Herbert Voß as he would be the most appropriate one to answer the question. In addition to that, his work is copyrighted and he would be the only one to edit the document. If you prefer I can delete the question as I had said before and keep it in meta.

Comment: This belongs here, not on meta, as it's not about TeX-sx but is about 'TeX things'.

Comment: My feeling is 'no': Herbert's books seem to be published in English by [UIT](http://www.uit.co.uk/Authors/HerbVoss), and while they list the _LaTeX quick reference_, that's a much longer text.

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, you are right it has different ISBN :). azetina: Comprehensive main book is in [German](http://www.lehmanns.de/shop/mathematik-informatik/27879417-9783865415639-latex-referenz) and [`LaTeX Quick Reference` in English,(UIT Cambridge,2011, US 15$ at amazon.com. ISBN 9781906860219](http://www.uit.co.uk/BK-LREF/HomePage) and it's [TUG Book Reviews](http://tug.org/books/reviews/tb107reviews-vossltxref.html). The pamphlet-type german `LaTeX Referenz` book(ISBN:9783865415561) in Q is `Chap:4(Command List)` and `Chap 5(Lengths and Counters)` in main book's `pp:41-78`.

Answer (score 1):

[That should have been a comment (treat as such, please!) but it's too long. There's also a hyperlink.]

In the accompanying [interview](http://www.lehmanns.de/page/latexreferenz) Voß himself refers to his "Big Reference Book" (271 pages) and the small one (32  pages), both of which he claims to be suitable for beginners and advanced users alike.

The small one, made available for free, is really just a (very short) "reference of environments, macros, lengths and counters". Voß claims that it's easier to find the descriptions and command syntax in a small collection rather than a fat volume, the latter only becoming necessary when you want to understand "what's behind the commands".

Q: *Why is the (short) "Reference" being distributed free of charge?*

A: TeX was one of the first "Open Source" projects in the world, without the expression actually having been invented. Distributing the "Small Reference" for free allows us to give back to the OS Community a little for the positive experiences we have had. It also serves to promote LaTeX in general, the low-cost DANTE edition of books, DANTE e.V. and Lehmanns Media.

(My translation)